# How to compress results into one line using the CASE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the CASE clause and trying to compress the results into a one line result.  Now, my data come back like this.

```
asset_id    ID_ISIN          ID_SEDOL     ID_CUSIP
131218      NULL             NULL         NULL
131218      NULL             2450915      NULL
131218      NULL             NULL         448814DM2
131218      NULL             NULL         448814DM2
131218      NA-000K0VF05-4   NULL         NULL
131218      NULL             2450915      NULL
```

I really want to see this.

```
asset_id    ID_ISIN          ID_SEDOL     ID_CUSIP
131218      NA-000K0VF05-4   2450915      448814DM2
```

Here is the SQL that I'm testing.

```
SELECT CW.asset_id,
CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END As ID_ISIN,
CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'SED' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END As ID_SEDOL,
CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'CSP' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END As ID_CUSIP
FROM CPDG As CPDG
INNER JOIN CW As CW
ON CPDG.asset_id = CW.asset_id
WHERE CW.asset_id = '131218'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need aggregation:

```
SELECT CW.asset_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number END) As ID_ISIN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'SED' THEN CW.id_number END) As ID_SEDOL,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'CSP' THEN CW.id_number END) As ID_CUSIP
FROM CPDG CPDG INNER JOIN
     CW CW
     ON CPDG.asset_id = CW.asset_id
WHERE CW.asset_id = '131218'
GROUP BY CW.asset_id;
```

Note:  I removed the `ELSE NULL` because that is redundant.  Also, if `asset_id` is a number (which I suspect it is), then remove the single quotes from the comparison.

Comment: That works!  How can I add an Update to that?  I tried this:

UPDATE Price_Test2
SET ID_ISIN = ID_ISIN,
SET ID_SEDOL = ID_SEDOL,
SET ID_CUSIP = ID_CUSIP
MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END) As ID_ISIN ...etc.  It's complaining about and incorrect syntax near 'SET'.